# How to find a class associated with div after querying it using nativeElement.querySelector

Tags: html, angular, karma-jasmine

so, I have this element which i am getting on

```
 const delDeptIconElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#del-dept-icons-0');
 console.log(delDeptIconElement)
```

below is console log in karma

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="del-dept disable-pointer" 
    ng-reflect-klass="del-dept" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"
    id="del-dept-icons-0">
<my-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="enable-pointer" svgicon="my-icons:icon-close" ng-reflect-svg-icon="my-icons:icon-close">
    <div class="my-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="my-icon">
        <div style="display: none"></div>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</my-icon>
```

I want to check whether `div` has `disable-pointer` class or not (as you can see `class="del-dept disable-pointer"` it has). How to do that ?

Also, I cant find any documentation for doing that while using `querySelector`.

Comment: Something like `delDeptIconElement.classList.contains('disable-pointer')`?

Comment: @yurzui : Thank you so much. Put it as an answer as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delDeptIconElement.classList.contains('disable-pointer')
```

did the trick.